# Excel If statement function is not returning values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is my first post and I'm looking for some help with some excel if statements (maybe a Sumifs?)

I'm trying to total a commission for employees based off if its been payed out and has the employees name. It will then take all the corresponding values and sum them under that employee for one total.

C = Commission F = Payed G = Employee

Here is what i thought the refined version would be to trouble shoot the lack of output:

```
    +If(And(G66:G69="Paul",F66:F69=""),SUM(C66:C69))
```

This returns a #VALUE! error

The Following is my original which i tried to refine:

```
     +SUMIFS($C2:$C999,$F2:$F999,$F2:$F999="",$G2:$G999,$G2:$G999="Paul")
```

This has the specific ranges i wanted (2-999).

This one returns $ -

I think I'm close this the second function but cannot figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I think you mean: `=SUMIFS($C2:$C999,$F2:$F999,"=",$G2:$G999,"Paul")`

Comment: @Rory In terms of the beginning being an = sign i do but was having a hard time getting it to post with that (not sure why so i went with option B, the +). on the "=" edit i need the F ranges to be only using cells that are blank. wouldnt "=" mean it requires that equals sign?

Comment: No - try it. :)

Comment: @Rory That did it! Thank you very much!